# find a string in DOM explorer using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to find the string in the attached picture using a vba in excel. I have the code below, but it is not finding the date that I am looking for.
The for loop to find is at the last "For Each Element In Elements2"

```
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim elements1 As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Elements2 As IHTMLElementCollection

Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium

Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
complete = 0

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://example.com"

With appIE
  .Navigate sURL
  .Visible = True

    Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
    Loop

   Do While complete <> 1

        Set Doc = appIE.Document
        Set Elements = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        Set elements1 = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("strong")
        Set Elements2 = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("td")


            For Each Element In Elements
                If Element.ID = "form-id" Then
                    requestnumber = Element.GetAttribute("Value")
                End If

                If Element.ID = "remedy-case-info" Then
                   CaseInfo = Element.GetAttribute("Value")
                End If
            Next Element



            For Each Element In elements1

            If InStr(1, Element.InnerHtml, "EM") Then

                For iCnt = 1 To Len(Element.InnerText)
                    If IsNumeric(Left(Element.InnerText, 2)) Then
                      NumericOnly (Element.InnerText)
                    End If
                Next iCnt
            End If
            Next Element
            AClientCount = tempcount



            For Each Element In Elements2

            '  If InStr(1, Element.InnerHtml, "td") Then
                    If InStr(1, Element.InnerHtml, "value-field align-top") Then
                            Requestdate = Element.GetAttribute("Value")
                    End If
            ' End If

            Next Element
            Set Elements = Nothing

       If requestnumber <> "" Then
          Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = requestnumber & " - " & CaseInfo & " - " & tempcount & " - " & Requestdate
          complete = 1
      End If
 Loop
.Quit

End With
```

[image]

Comment: If you do a `debug.print Element.InnerHtml` does the date show up in the immediate window as part of the entire InnerHtml? If so, use `Mid \ Left \ Right, etc.` to parse date out of string.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not picking up that phrase at all. I can see other phrases that falls with the td tag, but not this.

Comment: perhaps a debug.pring on all the `element2.innerhtml` will reveal the right one and you can then build a way to strip it out. Sometimes this is the only way i've found things in debugging website scraping.

Comment: debug.print element2. has only the following options (items, length, tag, string)

Comment: sorry, unfortunately, do to security restrictions where I am, I cannot scrape IE with VBA. Otherwise, I'd dig in more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The innerHtml property picks up the content within a tag but does not pick up the tag itself. The outerHTML property includes the tag itself as well as the tag's content.

Example:

HTML `<p class="fee fie foe fum">bar <b>bat</b> <i>cat</i> car</p>`

- innerHTML `bar <B>bat</B> <I>cat</I> car`
- outerHTML `<P class="fee fie foe fum">bar <B>bat</B> <I>cat</I> car</P>`

To perform a text match on an attribute value of an element, you would need to look at the outerHTML property of the element and not the innerHTML property.

However, the class attribute of an element can be accessed via the className property so you could replace the InStr on innerHTML with this:

```
If InStr(1, Element.className, "value-field align-top") Then
```

This is not ideal because it would be perfectly valid to write the class names in a different order - e.g. `class="align-top value-field"` - and this would not be picked up by the InStr function.

It would be better to start with getElementsByClassName (which doesn't care about which order the class names are in) and then use the tagName property to check we have the correct tag, like this:

```
Set Elements2 = Doc.getElementsByClassName("value-field align-top")

' code for the loops on Elements and Elements1 goes here

For Each Element In Elements2
    If Element.tagName = "td" Then
```

Finally, `Element.getAttribute("value")` will return Null unless the element has a named attribute called "value". To get the text value of the element, use this instead:

```
Requestdate = Element.innerText
```

Comment: Thank You barrow. Made the changes as per to your instruction and made my code to work. Thanks a lot.